# Manipulate JSON into specific rows for a table layout

Tags: javascript, arrays, pivot

I've got this array of objects

```
const raw = [
  {
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Refunds',
    amount: 469.34,
    adjAmount: 469.34
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Rent Income',
    amount: -2405.02,
    adjAmount: -2405.02
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'ADMIN',
    glFull: 'Sales',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Sales',
    amount: 2146187.47,
    adjAmount: 2146187.47
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'WAREHOUSE',
    glFull: 'Sales',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'ADMIN',
    glFull: 'Sales Variance',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Sales Variance',
    amount: -5369,
    adjAmount: -5369
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'WAREHOUSE',
    glFull: 'Sales Variance',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get it into the format of:

```
const desired = [
  ['', 'ADMIN', 'DB276', 'WAREHOUSE', 'TOTAL']
  ['Refunds', 0, 469.34, 0, 469.34]
  ['Rent Income', 0, -2405.02, 0, -2405.02]
  ['Sales', 0, 2146187.47, 0, 2146187]
  ['Sales Variance', 0, -5369, 0, -5369]
]
```

My issue is that admin and warehouse may or may not have a "refunds" (or other gl code) entry.
Another layer is that the `glFull` is not universal. Other locations may have different gl's.
I've been going crazy trying to figure out how to get it in the desired layout.
It needs to be in a multidimensional array because of the way the UI is displaying the table.
If I change it, I'd have to change a whole hell of a lot.

Comment: Lol. Thanks for the edit @adriano... I kinda didn't wanna change "hellofa" cause i was going for that drawl... but. Yes. You are very much right. Thank you. PS. i hate capitalizing I's...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works, but probably not the most optimized way to do this.

```js
const raw = [{
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Refunds',
    amount: 469.34,
    adjAmount: 469.34
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Rent Income',
    amount: -2405.02,
    adjAmount: -2405.02
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'ADMIN',
    glFull: 'Sales',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Sales',
    amount: 2146187.47,
    adjAmount: 2146187.47
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'WAREHOUSE',
    glFull: 'Sales',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'ADMIN',
    glFull: 'Sales Variance',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Sales Variance',
    amount: -5369,
    adjAmount: -5369
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'WAREHOUSE',
    glFull: 'Sales Variance',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  }
]

const generatePivot = () => {
  let markers = ['ADMIN', 'DB276', 'WAREHOUSE'];
  let header = ['', 'ADMIN', 'DB276', 'WAREHOUSE', 'TOTAL'];
  let glFullListAll = [];
  let dataTab = {};

  //Process data into a JS Object
  raw.forEach((item, i) => {
    if (!dataTab[item.wsDescPL])
      dataTab[item.wsDescPL] = {}
    if (!dataTab[item.glFull]) {
      dataTab[item.wsDescPL][item.glFull] = {
        amount: 0,
        adjAmount: 0
      };
      glFullListAll.push(item.glFull);
    }
    dataTab[item.wsDescPL][item.glFull]["amount"] += item.amount;
    dataTab[item.wsDescPL][item.glFull]["adjAmount"] += item.adjAmount;
  })
  
  //console.log(dataTab);
  
  //Convert JS Object to Array of Arrays
  let glFullList = new Set(glFullListAll);
  let desired = []
  desired.push(header);

  glFullList.forEach((g, i) => {
    let temp = [];
    let total = 0;
    temp.push(g);
    markers.forEach((key, i) => {

      if (dataTab[key][g]) {
        temp.push(dataTab[key][g]["adjAmount"]);
        total += parseFloat(dataTab[key][g]["adjAmount"]);
      } else
        temp.push(0);
    })
    temp.push(total);
    desired.push(temp);
  })
  
  console.log(desired);
  
  return desired;

}

generatePivot();
```

Comment: You and @adrian are so close! You've both given me great ideas! The rows cant have multiple of the same first index - "Sales" for example. It should be a singular row with the individual values or 0 if there isn't one

Comment: Can you recheck the code, i modified it to fix the issue of repeated entries.

Comment: You sir. Are a lifesaver! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a combination of [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like so:

```
const arr = [];

raw.forEach((item) => {
    arr.push(Object.values(item));
});

console.log(arr);
```

***If there are optional fields in the response then I would advise returning null values from the API instead of padding the array using JS.***

However, if you have no choice, then the only way I can see doing it is like so (this is pretty dirty):

```
const arr = [];

raw.forEach((item, index) => {
    arr[index] = [
        item.hasOwnProperty('wsDescPL') ? item.wsDescPL : '',
        item.hasOwnProperty('glFull') ? item.glFull : '',
        item.hasOwnProperty('amount') ? item.amount : '',
        item.hasOwnProperty('adjAmount') ? item.adjAmount : ''
    ];
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Yes. This is a way to create rows but does not solve my particular issue. I appreciate your go though! If you notice the "wsDescPL" is the column header and all rows need to match with this - in the correct order. It is an especially interesting puzzle. I've been at it all day. Also, i agree with you about the null values but unfortunately i do need to pad the ones that aren't there

Answer (score 1):

```js
const raw = [
  {
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Refunds',
    amount: 469.34,
    adjAmount: 469.34
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Rent Income',
    amount: -2405.02,
    adjAmount: -2405.02
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'ADMIN',
    glFull: 'Sales',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Sales',
    amount: 2146187.47,
    adjAmount: 2146187.47
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'WAREHOUSE',
    glFull: 'Sales',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'ADMIN',
    glFull: 'Sales Variance',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'DB276',
    glFull: 'Sales Variance',
    amount: -5369,
    adjAmount: -5369
  },
  {
    wsDescPL: 'WAREHOUSE',
    glFull: 'Sales Variance',
    amount: 0,
    adjAmount: 0
  }
];

const transform = raw => raw.reduce((results, item) => {
  results.push([ item.glFull, item.amount - item.adjAmount, item.amount, item.adjAmount ]);
  return results;
}, [['', 'ADMIN', 'DB276', 'WAREHOUSE', 'TOTAL']]);

console.log(transform(raw));
```

Comment: You got me close... If i can get it with your idea i'll give ya credit for sure... The duplicate first indexes need to be singular. and the length of each row needs to be the same...

Comment: if glFull is not universal you can or results so the one that has a value is used item.glFull || item.glOther will return the one that is not undefined.